# Using a LINQ query to populate a combo box with data from an access database

Tags: vb.net, linq

In VB.Net:

I am trying to populate a combo box on my form using data from a MS Access database. Specifically; taking all of the last names from the database, sorting them in ascending order in an output list which I named players and then adding each item in players to my combo box (`cboPlayer`).

```
 Public Sub GetPlayers()

    Dim PlayerLastName As New List(Of String)
    PlayerLastName.Add("Smith")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Hill")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Beyer")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Wilson")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Hudson")
    PlayerLastName.Add("van Zegeren")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Bibbs")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Muller")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Pierce")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Henry")
    PlayerLastName.Add("Johnston")

Dim Players = From Last In PlayerLastName
                    Order By Last Ascending
                    Select Last

    cboPlayer.Items.Add(Players.ToString)
    cboPlayer.SelectedItem = 0
```

I know this isn't exactly correct but not positive what direction to head in. When I run the program the combo box is populated with `System.linq.enumerated`.

Any ideas what that might mean or what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe over thinking it just a little?  Why not try without the linq, List has a sort function.  Also just bind PlayerLastName to the combobox.

```
    Public Sub GetPlayers()

        Dim PlayerLastName As New List(Of String)
        PlayerLastName.Add("Smith")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Hill")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Beyer")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Wilson")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Hudson")
        PlayerLastName.Add("van Zegeren")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Bibbs")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Muller")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Pierce")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Henry")
        PlayerLastName.Add("Johnston")

        PlayerLastName.Sort()    

        cboPlayers.DataSource = PlayerLastName
        cboPlayers.SelectedIndex = -1

     End sub
```

Edit:

or if you still want to us linq then, you need to change the linq return of IEnumerable to a List...

```
Dim Players = From Last In PlayerLastName
                        Order By Last Ascending
                        Select Last

ComboBox1.DataSource = Players.ToList
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, that does work! Unfortunately I am taking a class and the current topic is utilizing LINQ statements, otherwise your suggestion seems much easier and to the point. I am a trying to understand LINQ in general more than for a specific application which is why I am attempting to apply it to this specific scenario. Thanks again for the help though!